# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword').I use firebase @8.2.3 version

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword').I use firebase @8.2.3 version .
I have read the firebase implementation for that i copied the code exactly for the version i use (version 8.2.3) but it doesnt work,here is the code in my register.js

```
import "./Register.css";
import firebase from '../../../firebase';

const Register = ({
  history
}) => {

        const onRegisterSubmitHandler = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            const email = e.target.email.value;
            const password = e.target.password.value;
    
            console.log(email,password);
            
            firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
               .then((userCredential) => {
                 var user = userCredential.user;
                 console.log(user);
                 history.push('/home');
            });
        };
    
    
    return (
        <div>
      <section className="sec8">
      <form onSubmit={onRegisterSubmitHandler}>
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <p className="form">
         <label className="email">Email</label>
            <span className="ema">
            <input type="email" className = "email" id = "email" />
            </span>
            <label className="password">Password</label>
            <span className="passw">
            <input className = "passw" type="password" id = "password"/>
            </span>
            <button className="btnsig" type = "submit">Sign up</button> 
        </p>
      </form>
    </section>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Register;
```

I dont understand the isuue,plus my app becomes blank page if i write 'export const auth = firebase.auth();' in my firebase.js file,thats why i use firebase directly,not just auth().
Any suggestions